# How to log or print in Android Instrumental Test

Tags: android, android-instrumentation

In Android app, we could log out using

```
Log.d(TAG, message)
```

In the unit test, we could log out using

```
print(message)
```

What about in Instrumental Test? (I tried `Log` and `print`, doesn't work)?

Comment: `Log.d` inside Instrumental Test will work the same as your normal app source code, maybe you have some filter in your IDE log view.

Comment: Not true, you cannot see a normal log statement in an instrumented test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the normal

```
Log.d(TAG, message)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The log statements don't show up anywhere